# Azure security HTTPS vs VPN vs ExpressRoute?

Tags: security, ssl, vpn, https, azure

We're getting ready to release a Web API and I'm confused about the best way to secure it.

Users will request data like:
Browser -> HTTPS -> On-premise nginx -> ??? -> Azure worker -> Azure MSSQL

- Nginx already exists and is already configured and servicing requests via HTTPS
- Nginx will proxy the request to the Azure worker
- Azure worker is a light-weight OWIN app
- Azure MSSQL is a VM, on the same Azure subnet as the Azure worker

What's the best way to secure the link between Nginx and Azure? The options are:

1. Use HTTPS between Nginx over the public web to the Azure worker
2. Create a secured VPN between Nginx and the Azure subnet
3. Use ExpressRoute between Nginx and Azure

Also if the answer is "1", then is it redundant to do SSL across a secured VPN?

Comment: What do you mean "we're in the same DC as Azure" all Azure data centers are owned by Microsoft and used solely for Azure so if your in the same DC then you are using Azure for both services.

Comment: We're not in the same DC, I've corrected the post. Just in the same location with the option of ExpressRoute to go to Azure.